# JavaScript - Tell Date() to return in specific format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a date string and I want to convert it into a date object using `date()`. It's doing so but the problem is, `date()` processes any date as 'MM-dd-yyyy'.

I tried following code:

```
var myDate = '09-06-2017'; //which is a string and is in 'dd-MM-yyyy' format from my perspective

var selectedDate = new Date(myDate);
$scope.minDate = $filter('date')(selectedDate, 'yyyy/MM/dd');

console.log(selectedDate);
console.log($scope.minDate);
```

It will process this date as 06-09-2017 and if I pass '13-06-2017'(i.e. any value greater than 12) then it will throw 'Invalid Date' in console.

So I'm looking for a solution by which I can tell `date()` to process the passed string in a specific format.

Thank You.

Comment: Use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: You could give it duplicate flag if you feel so rather than downvoting.

Comment: You could do some research before asking a question that's already been asked, several times. The downvote prompt states *"**This question does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful"*.

Comment: OHH.. research.. that's what I think I was doing from the 3 or 4 hours before I asked here a question. And anyhow, the question you guys mentioned of which my question seems to be duplicate, has not the answer I'm looking for. So thank you very much for your kind responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With out using any libraries you can split the date in to parts and pass them to Date(year, month, day) constructor.

```js
var myDate = '09-06-2017';
var myDateParts = myDate.split('-');
var selectedDate = new Date(myDateParts[2], myDateParts[0] - 1, myDateParts[1]);

console.log(selectedDate);
```

Comment: It could've helped but the problem is that the date string is not static, and the date format can vary depending on the country of the user

Comment: then you need a library, perhaps moent.js. In other case the only solution would be doing a bunch of if/else what would be a dirty solution

Comment: Well, of course it is a dirty solution, but it seems I have no other option and I'm implementing it. Thank You for your help.. I've used ur logic ..

Comment: and also can u explain why u decremented month by 1?

Comment: Month starts from 0

Comment: Ohh.. cool, thanks.